# How do I add commas to the display of collection items if a collection has multiple products intelligently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have a collection of objects in `product.categories`.

What I would like to happen is for my list of categories to be printed out like:

Men, Women

If I do:

```
<% product.categories.each do |cat| %>
  <% if product.categories.count > 1 %>
    <%= "#{cat.name}, " %>
  <% else %>
    <%= "#{cat.name} " %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

That prints `Men, Women,`.

So without adding a billion rules to check for last element and all this stuff, how do I handle the following cases:

1. If there is one object, put no `,`
2. If this is the last of multiple objects, don't put a `,` at the end.
3. If this is the last object, in a collection of many, end with a `.` <-- This is a nice-to-have but not a must have.

How do I handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= product.categories.map{|cat| cat.name}.join(', ').to_s + "." %>
```

Try above, that will work. Do let me know if you want any else.

Comment: You need a space after the comma in `join`, otherwise you will get squished output: `# => 1,2,3,4,5,6`

Comment: The only issue with this, so far is that it adds a `.` to the end of a collection with just 1 object. i.e. `Men.`. How do I adjust for that?

Comment: Also...one question, if I wanted to add a link to this...i.e. I want `cat.name` to be something like `link_to cat.name, category_path(cat)`. How would I do that? I tried the code I specified but it just outputs it in text.

Comment: `<%= (product.categories.map{|cat| link_to(cat.name, category_path(cat)}.join(', ').to_s + ".").html_safe %>`

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
<%= product.categories.collect{|c| c.name} * ', ' %>.
```

The "asterisk" method ([`Array#*`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-2A)) is an alias for [`Array#join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join).
Note the period just outside the ERb tag.

Comment: Thanks for this. I prefer the other method - it is more verbose and clearer when I am reading through the code.